# Unable to get the tab content on right side

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a peculiar problem of tab content not floating on right side as its tabs are on right side too. Below is the picture to get a better idea:

[image: Tab Content on left]

I have tried floating the tab content right but not working. Rather its going past right where I can't see anything. This problem exists for both Live Chat and Mail Us tabs.

Below is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/HebleV/pen/vZYvGb).

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="tab-pane livechat wow animated bounceInLeft" id="chat">
     <div class="chatwidget">
                <a href="#" class="wow animated shake">Click for Chat</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

**CSS3**

```
.livechat {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
width: 50%;
background-color: #eee;
height: 370px;
text-align: center;
box-shadow: 0 0 20px grey;
float: right;
}
.chatwidget {
  padding: 150px;
  font-size: 24px;
 }
```

Comment: If I change `width: 50%` to  `width: 100%` it works for me...and for you? ... https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LLEOEZ

Comment: Also, using `float: right;` on an absolute positioned element does not work

Comment: If you want it 50% and right aligned, use `right: 0` instead: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OgPOJQ

Comment: If I change the width to 100% then it will have a fuller and wider div which will cover both ends. I want only a half div as depicted in the pic.

Comment: Like this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OgPOJQ

Comment: Oh wow cool. Yes it works. Thank you. But can you tell me why float:right did not work in this case?

Comment: Posted an answer for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To right align an absolute positioned element, use `right: 0;` instead of `float: right`, `float` has no effect on absolute positioned elements.

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OgPOJQ)

```
.livechat {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 50%;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #eee;
    height: 370px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px grey;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and also the explanation. I did try float: right with relative positioning and it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `float:right`, use `right:0px;`

```
.livechat {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #eee;
    height: 370px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px grey;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you add position: absolute to the livechat element you should add position: relative to its one of parent elements as below mentioned. Better it is to body tag. And put right: 0; instead of float: right;.

body{

```
position: relative;
```

}

.livechat {

```
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0px;
 width: 50%;
 background-color: #eee;
 height: 370px;
 text-align: center;
 box-shadow: 0 0 20px grey;
 right: 0;
```

}

Comment: Well if i add that to body then everything disappears

Comment: Then try to put it to another parent tag of the livechat element. It depends on where that parent element is located in the web page. Try following code.<div id="parent">
  <div class="tab-pane livechat wow animated bounceInLeft" id="chat">
      <div class="chatwidget">
         <a href="#" class="wow animated shake">Click for Chat</a>
      </div>
 </div>
 </div>

Comment: #parent{
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 400px;
}

.livechat {

 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0px;
 width: 50%;
 background-color: #eee;
 height: 370px;
 text-align: center;
 box-shadow: 0 0 20px grey;
 right: 0;

}
.chatwidget {
        padding: 150px;
 font-size: 24px;
}